# gdb on OSX unable to recognize 32bit unstripped ELF

Tags: macos, gdb

This gdb was installed via Homebrew on my OSX.
I wonder why gdb doesn't work on this file(I was playing pwn)on my OSX, while I can run it on Kali linux through VirtualBox.
I saw some people mentioned "Apple version gdb", is that the problem?
And how do I solve this?
I searched for answer quite a while and even asked my proffessor, please give me a hand!

```
➜ file bof
bof: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, 
BuildID[sha1]=ed643dfe8d026b7238d3033b0d0bcc499504f273, not stripped

➜ gdb bof
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
.
.
.
"/Users/me/Desktop/test/bof": not in executable format: File     format not recognized
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

> This gdb was installed via Homebrew on my OSX.

...

> bof: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
>   dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,

There are many ways to configure gdb.  The default -- if you don't pass any special options to configure -- is to configure in just what is needed for the host platform.

In this case, probably what has happened is that your gdb is configured for OSX -- meaning Mach-O and not ELF -- and so gdb can't read ELF files.  You can test this theory by typing `set gnutarget <TAB> <TAB>` at the gdb prompt (the tabs will cause completion, which is the only way I know of to list what was compiled in here).  Alternatively, you can try `show configuration`, though that just says what options were passed to `configure`, and so it needs interpretation.

One simple way to get out of this is to reconfigure with `--enable-targets=all`.  Then gdb will be able to read ELF files and other things as well.